# Best Way of Determining that Website is Being run in Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008

In my code behind I'd like to be able to tell that I'm running my web site project in Visual Studio (either Debug or Release).

I was considering testing for "localhost" but that's not perfect because we could be testing it locally on the server.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not exactly what you are asking for, but you check for

```
System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached == true
```

Answer (score 0):

```
this.Server.MachineName
```

Might help...

Answer (score 0):

This one works in either debug or release mode:

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Request.ServerVariables["SERVER_SOFTWARE"]))
{
    // you're running in IIS, not Cassini
}
```